# Issue with SharePoint 2010 CA People Picker

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

I am new to SharePoint development and just installed SP 2010 Foundation on my Windows 7 dev workstation. However, I am having an issue with the Central Access People Picker. It is not finding users or groups, local or on the domain, and instead giving an error. I have not changed many setting from the installation defaults, and the current authentication mode is Windows.

It is giving me the error in the attached screenshot, and this more detailed error in the event viewer:

> An exception occurred in AllUsers claim provider when calling
>   SPClaimProvider.FillResolve(): Default Membership Provider must be
>   specified..

I have already looked into whether this is related to missing Alternate Access Mappings, and I do not believe that it is the problem.

Where can I start to try to fix this?

[image]

Comment: Well, you can start by seeing which claims providers are configured for the web application in the web.config file. Look for the `<PeoplePickerWildcards>` node. These are the providers configured for the people picker of that web application.

Comment: You can set a default membership provider in the web.config as well.

Answer (score 2):

As it turns out, my development workstation had the default membership providers commented out in the machine.config file. (I have no idea why.) Restoring the default membership providers fixed this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment and I cant up vote, I found your solution helpful.The membership provider on the machine config file was empty. 
Added the below line from the machine config backup file

```
<add name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider, System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" connectionStringName="LocalSqlServer" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="true" applicationName="/" requiresUniqueEmail="false" passwordFormat="Hashed" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="7" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="1" passwordAttemptWindow="10" passwordStrengthRegularExpression=""/>
```

Finally the people picker started working.